# Swagger Springfox Configuration Issue When mix rest with SOAP

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have spring boot application that has rest and soap services before adding soap web services Every thing was working fine, and I  am able to access swagger-ui.html page 
after adding below code lines swagger stop working

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, SERVLET_MAPPING_URL_PATH + "/*");
    // Add custom Title to CXF´s ServiceList
    Map<String, String> initParameters = servletRegistrationBean.getInitParameters();
    initParameters.put("service-list-title", SERVICE_LIST_TITLE);

    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

below is application code on github

[Boot application with rest and soap](https://github.com/rashadsaif/ws-boot-example)

How to make both of them work rest and soap?

Comment: Thats because you've mapped the servlet bean to the root to handle everything.